# How to verbalize a mathematics expression in English?

Tags: expressions, mathematics

How do we express a simple mathematics equation in a way that could be understood by most people bad in mathematics? I have a formula like this:

```
Processing Fee = Base Fee x ( Your Bid / Original Price )
```

My initial thought is to verbalize it as such:

> The Processing Fee is computed from the Base Fee multiplied by Your
>   Bid divided by the Original Price.

But somehow I feel that this does not elucidate the fact that Your Bid divided by the Original Price is actually a ratio. How can I improve on this to make the statement clearer?

Comment: Simply insert "by the ratio of" in your sentence.

Comment: It has been a while since I did anything mathy but aren't ratios different than fractions?

Comment: If "people bad in mathematics" are your audience, I would avoid anything that mentions ratios, percentages and the likes :) They are _not_ commonly correctly understood :)

Comment: In everyday mathematics, **A x (B / C)** always gives the same result as **A x B / C** (it's only in programming contexts that the sequence of evaluation can affect the result). So the brackets are just an irrelevant distraction here. In light of that I see no reason for OP to be dissatisfied with his first "verbalisation", or to introduce the equally irrelevant concept of "ratio".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid some of the confusion, make it a bit longer and play a bit with the sentences :)

> You divide Your Bid by the Original price, and multiply that with the Base Fee to obtain the Processing fee.

Actually, this yields the same result as:

> To calculate the Processing fee, you multiply the Base Fee with Your Bid, and divide the result by the Original Price.

Answer (score 1):

I would say something like

> "the processing fee equals your bid over the original price all times
>   the base fee" in casual conversation.

In a more formal context where 'all times' seems out of place you might instead say

> "the processing fee equals the product of the base fee and your bid
>   divided by the original price"

which is an equivalent expression.

Answer (score 0):

You might use one of @oerlelens' solutions, and add the formula as well:

> *To calculate the Processing fee, you multiply the Base Fee with Your Bid, and divide the result by the Original Price. That is, 
>   Processing Fee = (Base Fee x Your Bid) / (Original Price )*

People who program, or who use Excel, might prefer "*" to stand for multiplication instead of "x".  In that case the formula would be:

> Processing Fee = (Base Fee * Your Bid) / (Original Price )